# Prime Numbers: 6k-1 mod rule (New Discovery?)

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization

I've noticed that although all primes follow the pattern of $6k - 1$ and $6k + 1$ which seems to be a somewhat known fact.

However, I also noticed that all the primes of the pattern of $6k - 1$ only need to be tested against those that are also $6k - 1$ (beyond the square root, to a sixth of its size). Has this ever been discovered before? Would this algorithm in theory be faster to find the largest prime faster than current algorithms?

In theory, all one would need to do is multiply six by billions of digits, and then mod once across the spectrum by all products of $6k - 1$, faster even if we know if those $6k - 1$ numbers are already prime.

For instance $6k - 1$ where $k = 100$, therefore we are testing if 599 is prime.
For this number we only need to test all $6k - 1 \times 6 \leq 599$.

Here is Java code that does a half-sieve and performs fairly fast since it doesn't mod, but merely crosses off multiples of each number in the sieve.

```
public class primesUnder {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int maxNumber = 100;
    int[] primesUnder = new int[maxNumber];

    for (int i=5, count=0; count < maxNumber; i+=6) {
        primesUnder[count++]=i; 
    }

    for (int index=0; index < maxNumber; index++) {

        if (primesUnder[index] != 0) {

            int x = primesUnder[index];
            int z = x+index;

            while (z < primesUnder.length) {

                primesUnder[z] = 0;
                z+=x;

            }
        }   
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Hint: if all the factors had form $\,6k+1\,$ then their product would be of the same form.

Comment: Every time I think I've discovered something new about prime numbers it turns out plenty of people before me had also discovered it, and probably also thought they were first.

Comment: That's fair. I'm not a mathematician in any way - just like messing around with them and doing research later.

Comment: Messing around with Maths, or Mathematicians? :p

Comment: But $n/6$ is _way_ bigger than $\sqrt n$ for $n$ greater than a few hundred! So why do you think your method would be faster?

Answer (score 19):

If a number $n=6k-1$ is decomposed as a product of not necessarily distinct primes
$$
n=6k-1=p_1\cdot\cdots\cdot p_t
$$
at least one of the $p_i$ must be of the form $6k^\prime-1$. This is actually pretty obvious using [modular arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) for the modulus $6$.

Indeed, no $p_i$ can be either $2$ or $3$ since the lhs is not divisibile by $2$ or $3$. Thus the displayed formula reads
$$
n\equiv-1\equiv(\pm1)\cdot\cdots\cdot (\pm1)\bmod 6
$$
and for it to hold at least one factor on the rhs (and in fact an *odd* number of factors) must be $-1$.

Comment: Okay. Thanks I don't know enough, just figuring things out on my own without research.

Comment: I don't really follow...is this a new discovery or not?

Comment: @Pureferret Not really, it's pretty obvious

Comment: @PierreArlaud I'm glad it's pretty obvious to some :P

Comment: @Pureferret Hmm let me put it this way: is the fact that banana are the same color as yellow tulips a discovery? I don't find any reference on google about bananas being the same color as yellow tulips so it must be some cool new thing I found out :-)

Comment: @PierreArlaud Imagine telling that tosomeone who is colour-blind; it's like your explanation to a non-mathematician.

Comment: @Pureferret So you *are* admitting my metaphore is nice :D

Comment: @PierreArlaud have you seen: https://xkcd.com/1053

Comment: What does lhs mean?

Comment: @MarcosPaulo: lhs = left hand side, rhs= right hand side

Answer (score 2):

You asked two questions, and the existing answer only responds to one of them. The answer to

> Would this algorithm in theory be faster to find the largest prime faster than current algorithms?

is no, but for a rather specific reason. The [ten largest known primes](https://primes.utm.edu/primes/search.php?Number=100) are all [*Mersenne primes*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime), primes of the form $2^p - 1$ where $p$ is prime. The reason is that there's a particularly fast way to test numbers of this form for primality, the [Lucas-Lehmer primality test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Lehmer_primality_test). (And as a side-note, Mersenne primes are all equivalent to $1 \pmod 6$).

Comment: And more fundamentally, any prime-sieve algorithms runs out of steam on large primes.

Answer (score -1):

With those formulas you get not-prime numbers i.e 6*8+1=49=7*7. also it is a known fact that it does not exist a polynomial formula to get prime numbers. However,this formula produces good results. I recommend you to read the wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_for_primes) about it. It will give you a better approach on this subject

Comment: He is not claiming that he has discovered a formula for prime numbers but rather a different way of testing if a number of the form 6*n - 1 is prime or not.

Comment: I agree with the already existing down vote and down voted this as well. 49 is not a number of the form $6k - 1$. 49 is a number of the form $6k + 1$. The question was about numbers of the form $6k - 1$. There was probably a reason for that. A composite number of the form $6k - 1$ always has a prime factor of the form $6k - 1$ but a composite number of the form $6k + 1$ doesn't always have a prime factor of the form $6k + 1$.